# Android максимальная яркость экрана на странице с QR кодом

Tags: android

Есть активность, которую нужно предоставить менеджеру в магазине, и хотелось бы зажечь экран на максимум при переходе, и вернуть настройку яркости при выходе.

Раньше я делал это через  `Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS`, но сейчас (API 33) нужно делать проверки, открывать настройки для разрешения, и прочее. При этом я проверяю другие приложения, и там такой проблемы нет. Есть легальный способ провернуть это действие, не заставляя человека копошиться в настройках и прочее?